# What is main use cases to build a kubernetes on a Raspberry pi cluster?

Tags: cluster

I want to evaluate the benefits of having a Pi Kubernetes cluster.

Mostly I read that this project is about learning Kubernetes and hosting personal websites. Well, I understand that the learning can be great but it seems to me when this argument is taken out what real useful use cases remain. And I would say hosting personal websites seems a little overkill.

Let me be clear I really like to build a cluster and love building stuff but this just looks like one of these projects that just takes a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

The same as Kubernetes on other machines, it has the same benefit on a group (more that one raspberry pi) of Raspberry Pis.

> ### What is Kubernetes?
>
> Kubernetes is a vendor-agnostic cluster and container management tool, open-sourced by Google in 2014. It provides
>   a “platform for automating deployment, scaling, and operations of
>   application containers across clusters of hosts”. Above all, this
>   lowers the cost of cloud computing expenses and simplifies operations
>   and architecture.

*[Source](https://www.developintelligence.com/blog/2017/02/kubernetes-actually-use/)*

---

> ### lightweight Kubernetes on Raspberry Pi
>
> The RAM and CPU requirements on the master node of Kubernetes
>   overwhelmed the raspberry pi. This caused poor performance when doing
>   various Kubernetes tasks. It also made an in-place upgrade of
>   Kubernetes impossible.
>
> As a result, there is the [k3s project](https://k3s.io/) here as a solution. The
>   [K3s](https://k3s.io/) has built as a "lightweight Kubernetes" for use in
>   resource-constrained environments. It is also optimized for ARM
>   processors. This makes running a Raspberry Pi-based Kubernetes cluster
>   much more feasible.

*[Source](https://opensource.com/article/20/3/kubernetes-raspberry-pi-k3s)*

---

***References:***

- [What does Kubernetes actually do and why use it?](https://www.developintelligence.com/blog/2017/02/kubernetes-actually-use/)
- [Run Kubernetes on a Raspberry Pi with k3s](https://opensource.com/article/20/3/kubernetes-raspberry-pi-k3s)
- [The certified Kubernetes distribution built for IoT, Edge computing & ARM](https://k3s.io/)
- [Everything I know about Kubernetes I learned from a cluster of Raspberry Pis](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/everything-i-know-about-kubernetes-i-learned-cluster-raspberry-pis)
- [What is Kubernetes (official page)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/)